# Add custom property to all View controls

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to add a custom property lets say:

```
Public string Reason = "It does not matter why I need this";
```

To all view elements (Button, Image, Label,...) instead of creating separated classes which inherits each control?

Preferable would be to add to:

```
public class View : VisualElement
```

But without modifying Xamarin class how?

Comment: Attached property not good enough ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/attached-properties

Comment: @TheGeneral No I need to change that value from custom renderer (and/ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible, you need to create the custom class for each control.

The only way it might be possible is to download Xamarin.Forms code from Github and add property there to VisualElement, it may work but it is more complicated than adding the property to any control you want to use (you would have to do this any time you want to update Xamarin.Forms to newer version).

Comment: Yeah... :/ well hope it would be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use extension methods

```
public static class ViewExtensions
{
    // Enables compilers to dynamically attach object fields to managed objects.
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.conditionalweaktable-2?view=xamarinandroid-7.1
    static readonly ConditionalWeakTable<View, ViewFieldsObject> ViewFields = new ConditionalWeakTable<View, ViewFieldsObject>();

    public static string GetPerson(this View view) { return ViewFields.GetOrCreateValue(view).Person; }

    public static void SetPerson(this View view, string person) { ViewFields.GetOrCreateValue(view).Person = person; }

    public class ViewFieldsObject
    {
        public string Person { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You can replace **View** with any class that you want.